# SFDX pull sample data from dev org

Tags: salesforcedx

I've created my SFDX project in my IDE (VSCode), pulled my app code from my dev org where I created it before using SFDX, pushed it to my Git repo, cloned a branch into my local repo, created a scratch org (Enterprise) and pushed my source to the scratch org. ([Big thanks for this blog from Christophe Coenraets.](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/07/migrating-existing-projects-salesforce-dx.html))

Now, I need to pull data from my original dev org, including the standard Contacts, Leads, Accounts, Opportunities, Cases that are pre-populated in Dev Orgs, as well as sample data in about 8 custom objects.

I'm looking at the [SFDX Dev Docs on Export/Import Data Between Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_test_data_example.htm), and I have some questions.

1. Isn't there some kind of bulk command, rather than specifying every field in every object you need in a SOQL query?
2. Do I have to create nested SOQL queries of multiple objects to maintain master-detail and lookup relationships?
3. My dev org has a namespace -- not the one I intend to package the app with. (I know... I'm learning.) I've managed all of that in my APEX and Lightning code (without hardcoding), but a SOQL query has to include the namespace prefix for the custom objects/fields. Will that old namespace prefix port to the scratch org (don't want it to.) Thankfully, when I pulled the source from the dev org, the namespace is not on my custom objects.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've found the force:data:bulk command, but only a brief paragraph here. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_test_data.htm  Looking for more docs now...

Comment: Found a good workaround for the namespace situation. I do have to use the namespace in the SOQL query to pull the data into DX, but I can open the json data file in the editor and do a quick Find/Replace to extract all the namespace prefixes, then save it as a newly named data file sans namespace prefix -- same with the -plan file.

Comment: did find any answers for above?

Comment: @RajendraSinghNagar -- see my workaround above. I didn't find any better solution.